# jQuery click action does not trigger onclick attribute

Tags: jquery, event-handling, jquery-events, jquery-click-event

I am having problems getting a function that clicks all search matched checkboxes. The click event seems to fire, but no checkbox gets checked nor is `myFunc()` called.

It works perfectly when clicking each checkbox manually, but who wants to do that with 40+ checkboxes - not my users.
You may wonder why I use a div-onclick instead of directly on the input checkbox. That is because I want give my users a **larger** area to click on than a small checkbox.

I want to provide my users with a single hyperlink to select multiple checkboxes that match certain attribute value(s).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<a href="#" onclick="clickAndCheckAllMatch('search for this text');return false;">some text</a>
<div id="*actual_ID*" onclick="myFunc(a, b, c, d);">
  <input type="checkbox" id="book-*actual_ID*" onclick="this.parentNode.click;return false;">
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function myFunc(a, b, c, d) {
  // does stuff
}
function clickAndCheckAllMatch(value) {
  $('div[onclick*='+value+']').each(function(idx,e){
  $('book-'+this.id).click();
}
```

**EDIT**
When I changed from *div* to *label* then I didnt have to correct the checkbox state. A *div* or block-element must have some issue there.
I also removed the onclick from the *div*s, which meant I was able to target the checkboxes directly and could change their ID values to just the *actual_ID*.

```
function clickAndCheckAllMatch(value) {
  $('input[onclick*='+value+']').each(function(idx,e){
    // e == this
    $(this)[0].click();
    if ($(this).attr('disabled')) {
      //do nothing
    } else {
      if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        //do nothing
      } else {
        $(this)[0].click(); // only one checkbox per ID
      }
    }
  });
}
function CheckAll() {
  $('#container input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').each(function(idx,e){
    $(this).click(); // notice the difference ?
  });
}
```

Comment: You probably should bind your event handlers with jQuery, since you're using it anyway. Old-fashioned "onclick" attributes are generally deprecated here in 2010.

Comment: Source for that claim?
Besides I cant use bind globally, since each div onclick is unique and its generated from a non-jquery part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to use the event to change the value of the checkbox, I would do two things:

1. To give the users a large area to click, use a `label` element, not a `div`. `label` elements are directly supported by browsers, you don't have to do anything to make them work. There are two ways to use them:

   ```
   <label><input type='checkbox'>Foo</label>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <input type='checkbox' id='chk1'><label for='chk1'>Foo</label>
   ```

   The former is nice because you don't have to use IDs (which have to be totally unique on the page, so it starts getting to be a pain); the latter is nice for markup situations where you can't have the `input` be a child of the `label` for whatever reason.
2. If you need to change the state in code, change the state directly rather than by trying to trigger an event. For instance, if I want to change the state of the checkbox `chk1`, I just do this:

   ```
   $('#chk1').attr("checked", true); // or false, of course
   ```

   ...or to clear all of the checkboxes in a container (useful for those "all" or "none" links):

   ```
   $('#container input[type=checkbox]').attr("checked", false); // or true, of course
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Just solved a problem like this, related to checkbox's event handler rendered by ASP.net like js code in the onclick attribute, which I wanted to trigger. First tried with explicitly calling jQuery click event, but after a while realised that I will not succeed this way. So the solution that worked for me is:

```
someOtherObject.click(eval($('input').attr('onclick')));
```

Cheers.

Comment: wooohoo, my first post in stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

`this.parentNode.click` should be `this.parentNode.click()`.

`this.parentNode.click` is just the method object. Calling it will not fire the click event of the div. You must add the braces after `click`, otherwise the event will not fire.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Pointy's comment, use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.theAnchorTagClass').click(function(){
    //Code to check all boxes here or do whatever else you need...
  });
});
```

Just substitute something like that for whatever element it is you're trying to capture the click event for.

Comment: Not looking a selector, besides there is no class on the mass-check links